# Problems with deriving FT from FS using impulse train

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

There are two of the same equation given for the Inverse Fourier Transform:

$$ f(t) = {1 \over {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) \, e^{j \omega t} \operatorname{d\omega} \;\;\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;\;\; f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X( f) \, e^{j 2 \pi f t} \operatorname{df}$$

which can be derived from the Fourier Series (1) $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{jn\omega_0t} $ or (2) $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{jn2\pi f_0t} $:

$$ \begin{align}
(1) \implies x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{jn\omega_0t}
\,&=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\frac{1}{T_0} \int_{-\frac{T_0}{2}}^{\frac{T_0}{2}} x(t) \, e^{-jn\omega_0 t} \operatorname{dt}}^{c_n} \cdot e^{jn\omega_0 t}
\,=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\frac{\omega_0}{2\pi} \int_{-\frac{T_0}{2}}^{\frac{T_0}{2}} x(t) \, e^{-jn\omega_0 t} \operatorname{dt}}^{c_n} \cdot e^{jn\omega_0 t}
\\
\,&=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\lim_{\omega_0 \to 0} \frac{\omega_0}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-jn\omega_0 t} \,\operatorname{dt}}^{c_n} \cdot e^{jn\omega_0 t}
\,=\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}} \Bigg[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j\omega t} \,\operatorname{dt} \Bigg] \cdot e^{j\omega t}
\\
\,&=\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Bigg[ \frac{1}{2\pi} \overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j\omega t} \,\operatorname{dt} \Bigg]}^{X(\omega)} \cdot e^{j\omega t} \,\operatorname{d\omega}
\,=\, \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{X(\omega) \big\}
\end{align} $$

$$ \begin{align}
(2) => x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{jn 2 \pi f_0 t}
\,&=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\frac{1}{T_0} \int_{-\frac{T_0}{2}}^{\frac{T_0}{2}} x(t) \, e^{-jn 2 \pi f_0 t} \operatorname{dt}}^{c_n} \cdot e^{jn 2 \pi f_0 t}
\,=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{f_0 \int_{-\frac{T_0}{2}}^{\frac{T_0}{2}} x(t) \, e^{-jn 2 \pi f_0 t} \operatorname{dt}}^{c_n} \cdot e^{jn 2 \pi f_0 t}
\\
\,&=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\lim_{f_0 \to 0} f_0 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-jn 2 \pi f_0 t} \,\operatorname{dt}}^{c_n} \cdot e^{jn 2 \pi f_0 t}
\,=\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \operatorname{df} \Bigg[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \,\operatorname{dt} \Bigg] \cdot e^{j 2 \pi f t}
\\
\,&=\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\Bigg[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \,\operatorname{dt} \Bigg]}^{X(f)} \cdot e^{j 2 \pi f t} \,\operatorname{df}
\,=\, \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big\{X(f) \big\}
\end{align} $$

Either equation will result in the same $ x(t) $. Choosing $ \omega $ over $ f $, or vice versa, is just a matter of preference. They are identical :

$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{X(\omega)\} \,=\, {1 \over {2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) \, e^{j \omega t} \operatorname{d\omega} \;=\; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f) \, e^{j 2 \pi f t} \operatorname{df} \,=\, \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{X(f)\}$$

---

An alternative way of deriving FT from FS is to use the sifting property of an impulse train (or Dirac Comb). Knowing that

$$ \delta(at)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(t) \,\,\implies\,\,  \delta(f) = \delta \Big(\frac{\omega}{2\pi} \Big) = 2\pi \, \delta(\omega) \;\;\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\;\; \operatorname{df} = \operatorname{d \frac{\omega}{2\pi}} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \operatorname{d\omega} $$

I can rewrite the FS $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{jn2\pi f_0t} $ in terms of an impulse train :

$$ \begin{align} 
(2) \implies x(t) \,&=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, e^{jn \omega_0 t}
\,=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, e^{jn 2 \pi f_0 t}
\,=\, \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, \bigg[ \, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{j2\pi f_0t} \cdot \delta(f-nf_0) \,\operatorname{df} \,\bigg] \\ 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, \delta(f-nf_0)}^{X(f)} \cdot e^{j2\pi ft} \operatorname{df} \,=\, \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f) \cdot e^{j2\pi ft} \operatorname{df} \,=\, \mathcal{F}^{-1} \big\{X(f)\big\} \\
\end{align}
$$

All good and make sense.... until I did a change of variable from $ f $ to $ \omega $ :

$$
\begin{align}
(1) &\implies
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, \delta\bigg(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}-n\frac{\omega_0}{2\pi}\bigg) \cdot e^{j\omega t} \operatorname{d}\bigg(\frac{\omega}{2\pi} \bigg) \\ &=\, 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, 2\pi \,\delta\bigg(\omega-n \omega_0 \bigg) \cdot e^{j\omega t} \bigg(\frac{1}{2\pi} \bigg) \operatorname{d \omega} 
\\
&=  
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, \,\delta\bigg(\omega-n \omega_0 \bigg)}^{X(\omega)} \cdot e^{j\omega t}  \operatorname{d \omega} 
\,=\, \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) \cdot e^{j\omega t} \operatorname{d\omega}}_{\text{where is my}\; {1 / (2\pi)} \;\text{???}}  
\,=\, \mathcal{F}^{-1} \big\{X(\omega)\big\} 
\end{align} $$

We know there has to be a $ \frac{1}{2\pi} $ scaling factor whenever we write a FT in terms of $ \omega $, but that factor disappears if I derive FT from FS using $ \delta $ impulse train instead. Could someone explain what went wrong? I always feel *dirty* whenever I see a $ \delta $ in my equation.

Comment: can someone help migrate this question to signal stackexchange perhaps?

Comment: I am not familiar with the derivation of the Fourier transform using the Dirac comb however, I think that the missing $1/2\pi$ can be found on $c_n$. Can you point me to a reference in which $X(\omega)$ is compeletely derived using the Dirac comb? I am attempting to answer your question with a complete derivation of $X(\omega)$ however I am stuck at one point involving the dirac comb

Comment: I couldn't find a reference where $ X(\omega) $ is derived using Dirac comb. All sources I searched for only derive $ X(f) $ and just stuff in a $ 1/2\pi $ factor for $  X(\omega) $.  I just happen to cross check that and hence the question. The $ c_n $ in $ X(\omega $ and $ X(f) $ has to be equivalent according to the definition of FS

Comment: yes they are equivalent however notice how $1/T_0$ inside $c_n$ is changed in your first derivation of $X(\omega)$ or $X(f)$. Compare how $1/2\pi$ is generated using $c_n$ in the original derivation.

Comment: @qcpz I guess I don't quite understand which derivation you need other than the two ways of deriving $ X(f) $ already provided in the question.

Comment: I specifically need the derivation of how $X(f)$ is formed using $\displaystyle{\sum c_n \delta(f-nf_0) }$ since you skipped the most crucial part of how it became $X(f)$. The answer to your question may also be found on that specific derivation

Comment: @qcpz both the Fourier coefficient $ c_n $ and $ \delta $ is a function of $ f $ hence the  $ X(f) $. There is no particular meaning to $ X(f) $ other than grouping the two terms. I can as well call it $ A(f) $ or $ \operatorname{whatever}(f) $

Comment: @qcpz another way of looking at is $ X(f) $ is the frequency content or spectrum of $ x(t) $ and $ \sum c_n \delta(f-nf_0) $ does exactly that - $  c_0 $ is the complex spectrum for $ f_0 $, $ c_1 $ for $ f_1 $ and so on and so forth...

Comment: In your second to last equality you just lose a factor of $2\pi$ in the definition of $X(\omega)$. They can't both be true...

Comment: exactly. If the $ 2\pi $ didn't get canceled out then everything is good and as you said, they can't both be true. The same reason I provided the standard derivation to compare that coming from a $ \delta $. Now we're certain that $ X(\omega) $ is false, the problem is .... where?

Comment: No I literally mean in one line you define $X(\omega)$ to be on expression and in the very next line define it to be a different expression. Look at the last two times you put an overbrace. It is not the same formula underneath the brace but you claim they are both $X(\omega)$.

Comment: @podiki well... that's just a property of dirac delta function where $ \delta(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) = 2\pi \delta(\omega) $.  I should perhaps remove the first two braces....

Comment: @KMC Now the issue is that the thing that has the over brace isn't $X(\omega)$, its $2\pi X(\omega)$.

Comment: the $ 2\pi $ has been cancelled out by $ \frac{1}{2\pi} $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131255/discussion-between-podiki-and-kmc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of the derivation, it is explicitly shown that

$$ x(t) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \overbrace{\Bigg[ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j\omega t} \,\operatorname{dt} \Bigg]}^{X(\omega)} \cdot e^{j\omega t} \,\operatorname{d\omega} $$

Which means

$$ x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) \cdot e^{j\omega t} \,\operatorname{d\omega} $$

And this is exactly the same expression in the second part.

So, I don't understand why one should expect an extra $2\pi$ when using Dirac Combs.

In fact if one defines

$$X(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j\omega t} \,\operatorname{dt} $$
then we have
$$x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(\omega) \, e^{j\omega t} \,\operatorname{d\omega}.$$

Notice the absence of $2\pi$ in the inverse expression.

Comment: Ahh you pointed a typo in my question (but the question still holds). The brace for $ X(\omega) $ shouldn't include $ \frac{1}{2\pi} $ - the FT leaves that factor to the Inverse-FT anyway.

Comment: @KMC If brace does not include $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ then $X(\omega)= 2\pi \sum c_n \delta(\omega-n\omega_0)$. I think the missing $2\pi$ lies there.

Comment: The $ 2\pi $ is cancelled out by $ \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} $

Comment: @KMC In the last step of the second part it is written $X(\omega)=\sum c_n \delta(\omega-n\omega_0)$. However, if you define $X(\omega)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)e^{-j\omega t} \operatorname{dt}$ then $X(\omega) = 2\pi \sum c_n \delta(\omega-n\omega_0)$ (notice the extra $2\pi$ here). This is because when $x(t)=e^{jn\omega_0t}$ then $X(\omega)= 2\pi \delta(\omega-n\omega_0)$. For reference check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional row 303, column number 5 for "Fourier transform non-unitary, angular frequency"